# Правильное построение ответа на вопрос

Tags: грамотная-речь, смысл

Правильно ли на просьбу «придумай мне способ доказать тебе, что я тебя люблю» отвечать «я ничего доказывать тебе не буду»?

Answer (score 4):

Нет, это не будет ответом на просьбу: человек не *доказать* ему что-то просит, а хочет сам "доказать" то, о чём говорит. Его интересует, **как**, каким способом ему это сделать, чтобы его доказательство было принято вами и чтобы вы сочли его убедительным.